# Purple spots in my shots!

Tags: nikon-d5000, spots

Related to [“Spots” in my pictures. :-(](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3504/spots-in-my-pictures), I've discovered these *lovely* purple spots in all of my recent (1500ish) shots, but they're much different than his smudges.

I'm shooting with a Nikon D5000 + Sigma 10-20mm. Here's a crop from a random shot (edited in LR to make the dots more distinguishable):

[image: purple spots]

What does it mean and what can I do about it?

Comment: Related question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/how-do-i-remove-dead-pixels-from-a-digital-photo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are probably the result of [defective pixels on the image sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_pixel), and are commonly referred to as "stuck", "dead", or "hot" pixels.

This is a common occurrence with image sensors.  There are several ways to deal with this problem:

- Replace the camera - this is probably the most expensive solution
- Replace the sensor - this may be as or more expensive than replacing the camera
- Sensor pixel mapping - this is often an option that can be used to avoid changing the hardware. If you send your camera in for support, the technicians can tell the software to ignore the dead pixels.
- Software mapping - there are different [software tools](http://www.pixelfixer.org/) that can be used to ignore dead pixels, but usually these work best if shooting RAW.
- fixing them by hand - this is time consuming, but you can just hand edit your images

Comment: Also, slightly unrelated, but there is a "Service advisory" for the D5000: http://www.nikonusa.com/Service-And-Support/Service-Advisories/gezwvxil/D5000%20Service%20Advisory.html so you might be able to have this repaired at low/no cost

Comment: Some camera bodies have hot-pixel mapping available as a user-accessible menu option. This is by far the best solution, but unfortunately many camera makers use this as a price differentiator, reserving the feature for higher-end bodies. Something to keep in mind next time you're shopping for a camera body.

Answer (score 3):

They look like stuck pixels, basically these sensor elements always output a high signal regardless of the incoming light. This is being incorrectly interpreted by the demosaicing algorithm resulting in purple spots.

As a sensor defect there is no "fix" as such but you can map stuck pixels in software which prevents them from contributing to the final picture.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the assessment that they are stuck pixels. My S90 recently developed a few stuck pixels, and while I want to send it in for repair, I have worked around it in the interim with an [Aperture adjustment preset](http://www.apple.com/aperture/whats-new.html#presets).

I imported a photo exhibiting the problem, then used the retouch tool to repair the image. I then selected Presets -> Save As Preset and titled it “Fix S90 Stuck Pixels.”

When I import from that camera, I select that preset, and all my images are repaired automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's been a while, but I had the same issue and I have found that it is called ["Purple fringing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_fringing) (Wikipedia).

The reason why I "dug" more and tried to understand the issue is that I don't think is a sensor issue (in my case and probably in your case also) because I experienced something like that with a brand new camera and lens - Canon 80D and 50mm f/1.8 lens.

You can see also my photo attached.

[image: Purple Fringing]

I hope it helps, even though it's been a while.

Comment: This is definitely not the same thing.